# How to find names with English characters in column?

Tags: sql, oracle

i will explain what is going on:
i have a table of CITIES with columns :

1. ID
2. NAME_UA - ukrainian name
3. NAME_RU - russian name
4. NAME_EN - english name

i have a problem that in some cities like Odessa, **NAME_RU = Odesa** when it has to be **NAME_RU = Одесса**.
so to solve that problem i firstly need to find all Latin,English... words in NAME_RU
i had one solution but it doesn't work right now:

```
SELECT * FROM CITY "c"
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE("c".NAME_RU,'[^A-Za-z0-9]') ;
```

any solutions?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do here or which results you are after.. See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 2):

Your regex is saying to find 1 character which is NOT a letter or a digit. The caret symbol is negating it.

So, if you want to find all `NAME_RU` which only contain English letters and digits, you can use the following regex:

`^[A-Za-z0-9]+$`

`^` says that this is the starting point of the string.

`[A-Za-z0-9]` defines the allowed characters (but only matches single character)

`+` says match the allowed characters as many times as possible (starting from 1 - meaning empty strings won't match. If you want to match empty strings as well, you can use `*` instead of `+`.

`$` says that this is the ending point of the string. So, only the allowed characters exist in the string.

Comment: @GermanVaranytsya . . . This does what the question asks.  Here is a db<>fiddle:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=23326e3fd97d130b0a4f9cc088024dc9.